# passing template (without a specification) to an std::thread() gives error : <unresolved overloaded function type> matching Error

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates

So, my task is to pass both vectors `char` & `int` in the template with two threads.

Why it cannot thread to reading the two containers ? Some push will be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>

void check(std::vector<T> values){

     for(T& it : values){

        std::cout<< it <<std::endl;
     }

}

int main()
{

  std::vector<int> int_values = {1,2,3,4,5};
  std::vector<char> char_values = {'a','b','c','d','e'};

    std::thread th1(check, int_values);
    std::thread th2(check, char_values);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The Error is:

`error: no matching function for call to std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>,std::vector<int>&)`

Comment: Try     `std::thread th1(check<int>, int_values);` and     `std::thread th2(check<char>, char_values);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check` is not the name of a function, it is the name of a template.  `std::thread` needs a function object so just using `check` won't work.

You can use `check<int>` to specify the `int` specialization of the `check` template be used, or you could use a lambda and let the compiler figure it out like

```
std::thread th1([](const auto & var) { check(var); }, std::ref(int_values));
// or even shorter
std::thread th1([&]{ check(int_values); });
```

Comment: Great ! It works perfectly, in fact, i was looking for other methods than specialization, many thanks ! @NathanOliver

Answer (score 2):

template deduction doesn't work with `std::thread`, so use

```
  std::thread th1(check<int>, int_values);
  std::thread th2(check<char>, char_values);
```

Another thing, why do you use pass by value here I think you should change that to be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>

void check(const std::vector<T> & values){

    for(const T& it : values){

        std::cout<< it <<std::endl;
    }

}

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> int_values = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<char> char_values = {'a','b','c','d','e'};

    std::thread th1(check<int>, std::ref( int_values ));
    std::thread th2(check<char>, std::ref( char_values ));

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

and `std::ref()` is to enable you to pass by reference because `std::thread` copies all args in an internal storage

Comment: Thank you, but, if you may, should i understand that you're talking about Thread Local Storage (TLS), so using (the copied) datas from this last one means that the (original) datas are not affected ?

Comment: @rekkalmd u r welcome. `std::ref(yourVector)` makes a wrapper containing a reference to your vector. so when the thread copies the arg, it will copy the wrapper and when it uses it it will be dereferenced to the original vector. and your original vector won't be affected because `check` takes a contant reference after the modification.

Comment: I get it ! Appreciate that Mr. @asmmo